# ERROR TypeError: this.statutForm.value.poste.subscribe is not a function

Tags: node.js, angular

i'm sorry there is a lot of questions about this error but mine is strange. The function worked and after some minutes it didn't work anymore. Without the line with "subscribe" the LocalStorage is working good. Thank you for your help, I spent a lot of time of this error .. :'(

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { StatutService } from '../statut.service';
import { Statut } from '../statut';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-accueil-admin',
  templateUrl: './accueil-admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./accueil-admin.component.scss']
})
export class AccueilAdminComponent implements OnInit { 

statutForm!: FormGroup;
//isSubmitted = false;


constructor(private statutService: StatutService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.statutForm = new FormGroup({
    poste : new FormControl(''),
    etat : new FormControl(''),
    client : new FormControl(''),
  });
}

  recherche() {
  //this.isSubmitted = true;
  console.log('Statut saisi', this.statutForm.value);

  let poste = this.statutForm.value.poste;
  let etat = this.statutForm.value.etat;
  let client = this.statutForm.value.client;



  this.statutForm.value.poste.subscribe((data: Object) => {


  // Tableau des clés et des valeurs de l'objet
  let keys = Object.keys(data);
  let values = Object.values(data);

    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      if (keys[i] == 'poste') { poste = values[i]; }
      if (keys[i] == 'etat') { etat = values[i]; }
      if (keys[i] == 'client') { client = values[i]; }
    }

  let leStatut = new Statut (poste, etat, client);
  this.statutService.addStatut(leStatut);

  [enter image description here][1]}); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.statutForm.value.poste` is not an observable, it's plain value of the field. If you want observable following the changes, you can use

```
this.statutForm.get('poste').valueChanges.subscribe(/* ... */)
```

or

```
this.statutForm.controls.poste.valueChanges.subscribe(/* ... */)
```

Comment: Thanks, the error has disappear but 'addStatut' doesn't store in localstorage
In statut.service.ts : 
  `addStatut(statut: Statut) {
    this.statuts.push(statut);
    let tabItems = JSON.stringify(this.statuts);
    localStorage.setItem('Statuts', tabItems);
  }`